# MongoDump index conversion error of 'bson.Decimal128' not supported

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

```
Failed: error dumping metadata: error converting index (<nil>): conversion of BSON value '2' of type 'bson.Decimal128' not supported
```

Any idea why this error is popping up? I am using the latest version (3.4) of mongo with both the remote server as well as the local machine.

Comment: Could you give some more context as to what you were doing that caused this, as well as some example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my error. Version compatibility issues. Check by running mongodump --version.

Turns out doing apt install mongodb doesn't install the latest version. Make sure to uninstall and remove mongo tools and update to latest version.

Comment: Not working after using latest mongo package downloaded from [official web site](https://www.mongodb.com/dr/fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1604-3.6.2.tgz/download)